# Net Core 3.1 probar web desde otro equipo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, net

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web en .net core 3.1 y me gustaría poder acceder a al misma desde otros equipos para probar y enseñar lo que estoy haciendo. He abierto un puerto en mi router, pero no sé cómo seguir. Creo que hay que poner algo en el código de la aplicación para poder acceder desde fuera. Y no se si tengo que configurar el IIS o es suficiente con el que trae el propio Microsoft Net Core, el ISS Express creo que es.

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Has intentando accediendo a la maquina + puerto. Ejemplo en el navegador escribes: NombrePC:4933

Comment: si, claro, pero nada. creo q en net core hay q hacer algo más pero no se que es exactamente

Comment: Otra pregunta, estas intentando acceder a la app ejecutandola desde visual estudio o en IIS?

Comment: en principio ejecutando el visual studio. Este abre un IIS express y ya no se si eso es suficiente. por lo que he visto en la web hay que decirle en el proyecto, creo, donde hay que conectarse de alguna manera

Comment: Quieres hacerlo LAN o que salga a internet ?

Answer (score 0):

intenta modificando el archivo launchSettings.json que se encuentra en la carpeta Properties
Modifica:

```
applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
```

A:

```
"applicationUrl": "https://0.0.0.0:5001;http://0.0.0.0:5000"
```

Luego intenta ejecutar tu proyecto con:

```
dotnet run
```

Si tienes más de 1 proyecto en tu solución:

```
dotnet run -p [NOMBRE_DEL_PROYECTO]
```